# (Xamarin, Android) How dose this code help Reduce Referenced Instances?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, garbage-collection, xamarin.android

I am reading the Garbage Collection documentation for Android at [Garbage Collection -- Reduce Referenced Instances](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection/#Reduce_Referenced_Instances), I am not quite understand the mechanism of this code

```
class HiddenReference<T> {

    static Dictionary<int, T> table = new Dictionary<int, T> ();
    static int idgen = 0;

    int id;

    public HiddenReference ()
    {
        lock (table) {
            id = idgen ++;
        }
    }

    ~HiddenReference ()
    {
        lock (table) {
            table.Remove (id);
        }
    }

    public T Value {
        get { lock (table) { return table [id]; } }
        set { lock (table) { table [id] = value; } }
    }
}

class BetterActivity : Activity {

    HiddenReference<List<string>> strings = new HiddenReference<List<string>>();

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        strings.Value = new List<string> (
                Enumerable.Range (0, 10000)
                .Select(v => new string ('x', v % 1000)));
    }
}
```

How does the HiddenReference work? If the GC will **recursively** scan the instances BetterActivity refers to, can't it see the list in strings field, and then all the strings in the list? I think I am missing something. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is that `HiddenReference` has a `static Dictionary<T>`. Every static object is considered a root object by the garbage collector. This means we have a managed, rooted object. In this case, the GC bridge does not need to check for potential references since it can be sure the object will never be collected.

One note: reducing references from within an `Activity` is something you should do if you see slowdowns during the GC process. If your app runs fine, don't bother optimizing.

Comment: Thank you ! Very clear answer. So this strategy is not Xamarin only, can it be used in some other .Net projects? Like WinForm, WPF?

Comment: This is Xamarin.Android only. We have to make sure the Java GC and the Mono GC cooperate happily. The reference-walk is a consequence of having these two worlds interacting with each other.

Comment: So in a general .Net project, the GC will not do a recursive scan? For what reason does Mono need to do a reference-walk to work happily with Java GC? Forgive my ignorance, thank you~~!

Comment: It has to do with when to allow an object being collected. We can only let it go if neither the Java world nor the managed world have a reference to it. The process is complicated. During a managed GC run, we replace all strong references to Java peer objects with weak ones. We then trigger a native collection. If the object is gone afterwards, we can let the managed object go (if it's eligible for collection). Otherwise we recreate the strong reference. To prevent peers from being collected we must check all potential references, hence the recursive scanning.